# positional arguments

Tags: python, function, positional-argument

I am trying to understand how the parameters to this `function` are interpreted:

```
def f(a, *, b):
   return a, b
```

It appears this `function` forces the caller to call `f()` with exactly 2 params and the second param should always be a named `b=` param. How do I decipher this from the `function` signature? Why does it not allow me to specify a middle argument for the `*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I decipher this from the function signature?

1. Arguments with no default value must be passed.
2. Arguments after a `*` must be passed by keyword if they are passed at all.
3. Extra arguments cannot be passed to "fill up" the `*` unless an argument name accompanies the `*`.

Since `b` has no default value it must be passed.  Since it is after the `*` it must be passed by keyword.  Since the `*` is "bare" (i.e., it is just the `*` placeholder and not a vararg like `*args`), no other positional arguments can be passed as "middle" arguments.

See [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) for a description of the keyword-only-argument syntax.

Comment: Great explanation, I understood it better than the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` alone is a Python3-only way to express that the following parameters are named arguments and can only be passed to the function as such.

[From the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

> Parameters after “`*`” or “`*identifier`” are keyword-only parameters and may only be passed used keyword arguments.